# Add dynamic key to custom Object in spring java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

May I ask? how to insert the dynamic key in custom object

[image: This the current output]

I create DTO but I didnt expect the output is the image above

```
public class TransactionDetailDto {

  public List<TransactionDetail> transactionDetails;

  public String remarks;

  public TransactionDetailDto() {
    super();
  }

  public TransactionDetailDto(List<TransactionDetail> transactionDetails, String remarks) {
      this.transactionDetails = transactionDetails;
      this.remarks = remarks;
  }
```

Service

```
List<TransactionDetail> transactionDetail = transactionDetailService.getPoNoAndTransactionHeaderID(poNo, transactionHeaderId);

      TransactionDetailDto trans = new TransactionDetailDto();

      for (TransactionDetail transDetail : transactionDetail) {
          trans = new TransactionDetailDto(transactionDetail, transDetail.getSalesInvoice().getSalesInvoiceRemarks());
      }

    return trans;
```

Comment: The remarks String is not a part of the transactionDetails list, why do you expect it to be inside the corresponding json array?

Comment: It is possible? To response it in one object sir @IslamEl-Rougy

Comment: They are currently in the same object, the object itself consists of a JSON array representing the list and a property representing the remarks string.

Comment: I want to create a an temporary dynamic key if it is possible? Yes it is property representing the remarks, I hope it was inside sir @IslamEl-Rougy